# MySQL ORDER BY statement returning boolean?

Tags: php, mysql

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening, but my simple MySQL statement using an `ORDER BY ... DESC` command gives a really weird error when I try to perform the query.
The error is

```
mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in E:/.../home.php on line 23
```

And my code is:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blogposts` LIMIT 0, 30 ORDER BY id DESC");
while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))//error here
```

I can't find out why. Any help is appreciated. 
Oh, by the way, I know that everyone who looks at this question is going to rip into me for still using `mysql.*` libraries and there will be a highly upvoted comment about the evils of it and the fact that I am vulnerable to SQL injection. To answer before it's asked, as it were, this is not going online, it's purely a home project running on localhost. So don't even bother lecturing me.

Comment: +1 for pre-empting the boring mysqli sermon.

Comment: @OllieJones thanks :). I get so sick of the same comments with 5 million upvotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER BY` clause must come before the `LIMIT` clause

```
SELECT * FROM `blogposts` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: It is the syntax for `SELECT` statement, see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html